# How to call boost::asio async functions

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I want to use boost::asio deadline_timer on my asynchronous call. I want to call function A::fun(0) on calling object. To do I do sth like that:

```
io_service io;
deadline_timer timer(io, boost::posix_time::seconds(10));
timer.async_wait(&A::fun, this, 0); //error
io.run();
```

In the second line I got error : basic_deadline_timer::async_wait(const WaitHandler &)' : expects 1 arguments - 2 provide.

I used the same syntax as for starting boost::threads on some tasks, and I thought it would work.

Comment: Have you read the documentation? http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_deadline_timer/async_wait.html It explicitly says what arguments you shoud use.

Comment: Ok, now I believe timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&A::fun, this, _1) (0)  ); should work but is reaises many many errors. As it is explained here http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer3.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass a single function object which meets the [WaitHandler](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/WaitHandler.html) requirements; that is, which accepts an error code as its argument.

In C++11 I'd use a lambda:

```
timer.async_wait([this](const boost::system::error_code &){fun(0);});
```

In C++03, use Boost.Bind to make a function object:

```
timer.async_wait(bind(&A::fun, this, 0));
```

In either case, you probably want to check the error code that was passed (in the second case, by modifying or wrapping `fun`) to make sure that the timer really has expired.

Comment: That's correct. But how do I use is it to call function with 3 arguments?  timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&FileSystem::Open, this, pathname, openMode, filePerm)) will raise 89 errors.

Comment: @cygi1989: That should be fine, if `*this` is a `FileSystem` and `Open` does take three parameters. How is `Open` declared? What are the first few errors?

Comment: virtual int Open(const char* pathname, int openMode, int filePerm = 0). I am implementing the method in the base class (which is abstract).  error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<_bi::dm_result<MT::* ,A1>::type,boost::_mfi::dm<M,T>,_bi::list_av_1<A1>::type> boost::bind(M T::* ,A1)' : expects 2 arguments - 5 provided
see declaration of 'boost::bind'   error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<Rt2,boost::_mfi::cmf8<R,T,B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7,B8>,_bi::list_av_9<A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9>::type> boost::bind(boost::type<T>,R (__thiscall T::* )(B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7,B8) const,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9)' : expect11

Comment: anyway another method which just takes one int argument works fine

Comment: @cygi1989: Perhaps you could update the question with enough code to reproduce the problem; it's hard to guess what's going wrong here. Perhaps there's another overload of `Open`?

Comment: @cygi1989: Also, since that evil function takes a raw pointer for its `pathname` argument, be very careful that the string it points to still exists when the handler is run. If the string is managed by a local `std::string`, for example, then it will be destroyed when this function returns.

Comment: Huh, I had another function which differs only by the fact that instead of const char* it take string as argument (user friendly). When I removed/changed the function everything works fine. Does it means that binding does not handle overriding? Many thanks!

Comment: @cygi1989: Binding doesn't work well with overloads. You can make it work by casting the function pointer to the type of the required overload e.g. `static_cast<void (A::*)(int)>(fun)`, but that gets very tedious. If you can, use lambdas: I find they make this kind of code massively more readable.